# Custom Gradle task to execute all unit tests in all modules

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle, groovy, gradle-task

I would like to write a custom task for an **Android** application project with **multiple** Gradle modules which executes the unit tests in the following modules so I can run all of them with one **Gradle task** invocation:

- Android application module, e.g. `testOrangeDebugUnitTest`
- Android library modules, e.g. `testDebug`
- Java/Kotlin library modules, e.g. `test`

## Requirements

1. It would be convenient to being able to configure **one product flavor** (e.g. “orange”) to being tested (running all would take too long).
2. Also, running Android unit tests with the `debug` **product type** is sufficient.
3. **Modules names** should **not be hardcoded** so that the project is extensible and tests in new modules are picked up automatically.

## Draft

Here is my work in progress approach:

```kotlin
// buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/com/example/TestAllModulesTask.kt
abstract class TestAllModulesTask : DefaultTask() {

    private companion object {
        val DISALLOWED_BUILD_TYPES = setOf("release")
        val DISALLOWED_PRODUCT_FLAVORS = setOf("blue", "green")
    }

    private val allowedTestTasks = mutableListOf<Pair<Project, Test>>()

    init {
        project.subprojects
            .forEach { subproject ->
                subproject.tasks
                    .filterIsInstance<Test>()
                    .filter { !it.namedWithAny(DISALLOWED_BUILD_TYPES) }
                    .filter { !it.namedWithAny(DISALLOWED_PRODUCT_FLAVORS) }
                    .forEach { task ->
                        println(":${subproject.name}:${task.name}")
                        allowedTestTasks.add(subproject to task)
                    }
            }
    }

    override fun getDescription(): String {
        return "Runs all tests for all modules except for disallowed build types and product flavors."
    }

    override fun getGroup(): String {
        return "verification"
    }

    @TaskAction
    fun action() {
        println(allowedTestTasks)
        // TODO Execute all the allowedTestTasks with ./gradlew
    }

    private fun Test.namedWithAny(disallowedTerms: Set<String>): Boolean {
        return disallowedTerms.any { name.contains(it, ignoreCase = true) }
    }

}
```

Then register the custom task:

```
// /build.gradle
import com.example.TestAllModulesTask

tasks.register("testAllModules", TestAllModulesTask)
```

## Questions

1. What would be a modern way to collect all the test tasks and wire them with the custom task? I don't really like the string comparison here. Filtering by build type and product flavor would be appreciated.
2. How do I tell the custom task to actually execute all the test tasks which were collected?

## Related

- [Authoring Tasks](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html)
- [Task Configuration Avoidance](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/task_configuration_avoidance.html)

Comment: What have you tried? Should be a case of finding all the tasks (by name or type) and then making your new task depend on them all

Answer (score 2):

```
tasks.register("specialTest") {
}

gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    subprojects {
        var subTask = rootProject.findProject(":${it.name}").tasks.named("test")
        rootProject.tasks.specialTest.dependsOn subTask
    }
}
```

Rudimentary, but effective.  It creates the task you want to run, then loops over sub-modules (which can be filtered with an `if` statement), and applies the sub-module's task to the created task.  Works in Gradle 8.5